# How can I select an element with a specific inline style?

Tags: jquery

Suppose there are three elements as below

```
<div id="tab01">tab01</div>
<div id="tab02" style="display: none;">tab02</div>
<div id="tab03" style="display: none;">tab03</div>
```

How can I use jQuery to select an element that don't have an inline style `display: none`?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can select hidden elements with `:hidden`, and visible elements with `:visible`...

```
$('div:visible');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/PwV4X/).

...but if you specifically need elements which don't have `display; none` set as an inline style, try this...

```
$('div').filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr('style') == undefined || $(this).attr('style').indexOf('display: none;') == -1
}).
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/Uqk8c/).

...of course, if you are relying on this, you should rethink your problem.

Comment: Your suggestion is great! but your code is just selecting the element with "display:none", how about selecting the element without "display:none"?

Comment: @Charles Yeah, I accidentally did the opposite! Check the update :)

Comment: @alex Thanks! you're awesome... question - what is up with the 0 and -1... where do you figure how to do that at?  And there needs to be a semicolon at the end of the -1;  I was getting an error and figure that was why - oh and warnings to use === instead of ==

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question and found this helpful post.  The above answer is sufficient but I wanted to do it without using the indexOf method because it didn't seem as intuitive to me.

Here is what I came up with and the associated bin.  I left the above answer's code in there to show they both work.  Hope this helps as an alternative method.
http://jsbin.com/coroxa/1/edit?html,js,output

```
$('.bottom-drawer').filter(function() {
    //return $(this).attr('style').indexOf('display: block;') === 0;
    return $(this).is("[style*='display: block']") === true;
}).slideToggle(620);
```